# global name 'unhex' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on flask and on executing this statement

```
salt=os.urandom(32)

db_session.execute('insert into posUsers values (?, ?, ?, ?)',[usern,unhex("sjg"),salt,row.clientId])
```

its giving this error that unhex is not defined!

Update- Now I changed to this

```
db_session.execute('insert into posUsers (username,passwd,salt,clientId    ) values (?,UNHEX("6568"),UNHEX("haf"), ?)',[usern,row.clientId])
```

its giving a new error  'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
Any solutions ?

Comment: The code you posted would raise a `SyntaxError` since `un   hex("sjg")` is not valid python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you are passing it to an python list it is treated as an python function which doesnot exist.

You need to include it in sql query string.

```
salt=os.urandom(32)

db_session.execute('insert into posUsers values (?,unhex("sjg"),?, ?)',[usern,salt,row.clientId])
```

unhex is a mysql function and it is being treated as python function resulting in error